# rails - Update View when Form is Submitted without Refreshing the Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I'm building a Rails app in which there are exercises and user_answers. When the user sees an exercise, there is a form that he can submit with the answer he thinks is right.

**When submitting, I want the same view to be shown, without a refresh, but with a new div which has the solution of the exercise.** The view shown is the exercises/show and a form rendered in the user_answers folder. Right now, my code looks like this:

**exercises/show.html.erb**

```
    <div class="container exercise-page">
  <h2 class="exercise-title">Exercício <%= @exercise.id %> de <%= @exercise.category %> - <%= @exercise.sub_category %></h2>

<br>
  <%= render 'user_answers/user_answer_form' %>

  <br>
  <div id="solution_exercise">
  </div>
```

**user_answers/_user_answer_form.html.erb**

```
  <%= simple_form_for [@exercise, @user_answer], authenticity_token: true, remote:true, :method => 'POST', :html=> { class: 'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-3 mx-auto text-center list-group', id:"form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :answers, include_id: false do |answer| %>
    <%= f.input_field :answer, 
        label: 'Answer',
        as: :radio_buttons,
        class: 'form-check-input',
        :item_label_class => 'list-group-item',
        name: 'answer',
        collection: @answers, label_method: :answer %>
        <br>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit Answer!', class: "btn btn-outline-success", id: "submit" %>
  <% end %>
```

**user_answers_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @user_answer = UserAnswer.new(user_answer_params)
    @answers = Exercise.find(params[:exercise_id]).answers
    @exercise = Exercise.find(params[:exercise_id])
    @user_answer.exercise = @exercise
    @user_answer.answer = @exercise.answers.find(params[:answer])
    @user_answer.user_id = current_user.id
    @user_answer.save
    
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end     
end
```

**user_answers/create.js.erb**

```
solution = document.querySelector("solution_exercise")
solution.innerHTML = '<%= j render partial: "solution" %>'
```

**user_answers/_solution.html.erb**

```
<p>Your answer: <%=current_user.user_answers.last.answer.answer%></p>
```

**The error:**

[image]

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try rebooting the app. If the error persists check your console and try to find a line like this  : `Processing by WhateverController#action as HTML` .. You will know what format is requested; This could help narrow down the problem.

Comment: I rebooted it and got this in the terminal: 

Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms | Allocations: 8439)
  
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  
app/controllers/user_answers_controller.rb:30:in `create'

Comment: Try to remove your respond_to block. If your form sends as UJS then it should pick the JS erb file. Also make sure you have UJS gem somewhere or through node modules. Also your JS has an error : `const solution = document...` (but obviously not the problem)

Comment: I'm using Rails 7, so I think I already have UJS installed, but maybe not. I removed the respond_to block and ran `yarn add @rails/ujs`. Rebooted the app and it gave me the following error: `UserAnswersController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant.
request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []`

It seems like it's not assuming JS as a default format, Idk why :/

Comment: Have you imported UJS in your `javascript/application.js` file ? Also I recommend switching to Turbo / Hotwire / Stimulus instead of UJS if you have Rails 7. It requires a bit of learning and practice but much cooler than UJS .. (and it actually replaces it)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your precious time. I ended up doing it with Turbo/Hotwire using this awesome tutorial: https://www.hotrails.dev/

I wasn't using this because I didn't know if turbo is common in other web languages, but oh well, served its purpose for this case. Thanks a lot again!